# Params appear broken in ROS2?

Tags: ros, ros2, parameters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Node-arguments/#parameters, if I have a properly formatted parameters yaml file, and I call `ros2 run` with `__params:=` pointing to that file, I should see the parameters defined in that file listed when I run `ros2 param list`, correct?

I'm doing this, but the only parameter I see when running that command is `use_sim_time`, which appears whether or not I pass the parameters.

The parameter file is getting parsed, I know this because if I don't have `ros__parameters` in there or some other inappropriate syntax it will complain and exit without running the node.

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 on ROS Dashing. Is there any other useful info about my setup that I could provide?

I'm also a little confused on the expected node name within the parameters file. Does it need to match exactly the node name I provide when I call `ros2 run`? That is what I've been doing, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327835/params-appear-broken-in-ros2?/) by [actinium226](https://answers.ros.org/users/44013/actinium226/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2019-07-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I should see the parameters defined in
> that file listed when I run ros2 param
> list, correct?

Not necessarily. ROS 2 parameters machinery is slightly different from ROS 1 and in your case I guess that the main difference that you have to be aware of is that parameters have to de 'declared'. See for instance the [list_parameters.cpp](https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/master/demo_nodes_cpp/src/parameters/list_parameters.cpp#L32) demo, or e.g.

```
node->declare_parameter("foo");
```

Without this bit, the `foo` parameter from your yaml file **will not** be loaded and that's probably your issue at the moment. It is still parsed, as you verified yourself, but still not loaded as you'd expect.

If it happened that you can't know all of the parameters beforehand, then you can pass a particular config when instantiating your node so that it `allow_undeclared_parameters`. See an example at the [parameter_blackboard.cpp](https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/master/demo_nodes_cpp/src/parameters/parameter_blackboard.cpp#L28) demo.

Notice that the same functionality exists in Python (rclpy) too.

> I'm also a little confused on the expected node name within the parameters file
> Does it need to match exactly the node name I provide

Yes, the node name in the yaml file should match the name of your node, e.g. ["parameter_blackboard"](https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/master/demo_nodes_cpp/src/parameters/parameter_blackboard.cpp#L25) in the
[parameter_blackboard.cpp](https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/master/demo_nodes_cpp/src/parameters/parameter_blackboard.cpp) demo.

---

Originally posted by [artivis](https://answers.ros.org/users/11816/artivis/) with karma: 65 on 2019-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [actinium226](https://answers.ros.org/users/44013/actinium226/) on 2019-07-08**:
Aha, that was it. I enabled allow_undeclared_parameters and that got it going. I'll make a PR against the parameters documentation to mention this. Thanks for the help.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2019-07-08**:
Thanks, I updated that tutorial to use `parameter_blackboard` specificially, which sets those settings, but didn't really mention why I guess. A pr would be awesome! In a previous version (Crystal and earlier) you could do what you described, and that demo just used talker, which has no special configurations.

**Comment by [actinium226](https://answers.ros.org/users/44013/actinium226/) on 2019-07-08**:
PR Here: https://github.com/ros2/ros2_documentation/pull/297

**Comment by [kyubot](https://answers.ros.org/users/40914/kyubot/) on 2022-03-29**:
I am having exactly same issue when passing a yaml file to a node using launch.py.
If I use rclpy for my node, how to set allow_undeclared_parameters ?